# Adding Multiple worksheet with excel while export in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

Actually i am looking to export an excel file from dataTable. I managed to do it. But how can i add an empty sheet in the same excel file while exporting from dataTable?

Here is my code :

```
 public void ExportToExcel(DataTable dts)
    {
        if (dts.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string filename = "2.Dependent Master.xls";
            System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
            DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
            dgGrid.DataSource = dts;
            dgGrid.DataBind();

            dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);

            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");

            Response.Write(tw.ToString());

            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks in Advance !!!!

Comment: Does your DataSet have more than one DataTable in it?

Comment: Nope. I have only one datatable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add multiple worksheets with simple HTML.

instead of you can use Closed XML open source library

https://closedxml.codeplex.com/

Sample

```
 var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
 var worksheet1 = workbook.Worksheets.Add(PassYourDatatable1);
 var worksheet2 = workbook.Worksheets.Add(PassYourDatatable2);
```

[How to add Datatable to worksheet](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Adding%20DataTable%20as%20Worksheet&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: yeah, I have been using closedxml a lot in my projects. This is a super awesome library.

Comment: is it possible to export the data's from dataTable using closedxml ?

Comment: @MohamedMuzammilIrfan yes you could directly dataTable to worksheets

Comment: Thanks, It works. But i have a problem with date column. It shows as a string in excel. How can i convert it to date.  My Code to Convert the values of date field is  :    string strr9 = mem_item.Substring(247, 11);
                                        DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(strr9, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                                        string x = date1.ToString("d-MMM-yyyy");

Comment: @MohamedMuzammilIrfan you need like this string strr9 = mem_item.Substring(247, 11); DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(strr9, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); string x = date1.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");

Comment: Yeah, i used the same concept in function to export excel... There its correct...

Comment: @MohamedMuzammilIrfan mark it as answer if i am correct it will help to others

Comment: is it possible to add multiple sheets with my above posted code for export to excel function?

Comment: @MohamedMuzammilIrfan yes you could access each cell of each worksheets in workbook

Comment: how to remove the compatibility mode in Closed XML. Because when i used to open or save as  with Excel 97 / 2003. I have an issue to save. Any solutions?

Comment: ClosedXML could work with .xslx files only. User needs to save as .xslx file to .XSL ....97/2003 format